# Oracle JDBC ResultSet doesn't return correct data set

Tags: oracle, jdbc, resultset

I noticed this issue when exporting the Oracle SQL execution result from Intellij.

sql is `"SELECT TableA.seq||'-'||TableB.id doc_id FROM schemaA.TableA JOIN schemaB.TableB JOIN schemaA.TableC JOIN schemaA.TableD ON ...."`

The `SELECT COUNT(doc_id)` result is `137272` in total, however, the exported CSV file has less than 137272 (sometimes 137258, not fixed) lines.

I checked the result, surprisingly found that there are duplicated doc_id which was not expected.

But if I add `ORDER BY doc_id` in sql and re-export the result, everything becomes fine.

I thought it might be caused by paging thus I wrote a Java program to get the data. No luck, the output file also has less than 137272 lines, and with some duplicated lines.

If I change the FetchSize to 1000, sometimes the result is OK. If the fetchsize is 100, always no luck.

I could not figure out the problem, is my usage of JDBC wrong?

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_CONNECTION,
        JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD)) {
    try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement(); FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("out.txt")) {
        statement.setFetchSize(100);

        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                fw.write(rs.getString(1));
                fw.write("\n");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // not shown in this code snippet
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you execute the exact SQL in a tool like Toad or SQL Developer, sending output to a file? That's where I would start: what happens when running the same SQL by hand, then worry about if Java is doing something different.

Comment: @TadHarrison Thanks. I have also used dbeaver and intellij database tools to export, same situation happened.

Comment: So it's not a Java problem, it's a SQL problem, correct?

Comment: @TadHarrison Both DBeaver and IntelliJ are Java based, so that is not a good conclusion.

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using, and what is your Oracle database version?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, they are Java based, but it is still a good conclusion--don't waste time trying to find a Java bug if the SQL itself is not sound. Try a non-Java tool if necessary. Spool it to a file from SQL*Plus.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel database version is `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`, client is `ojdbc7 12.1.0.1.0`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have also queried by using SQL * PLUS. Same result.